# Why injecting pubnub.angular.service after injecting ngRoute is throwing error in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject dependency  for my app on "ngRoute" as well as "pubnub.angular.service".

I have written to separate apps having this dependency injection separately and my codes are working.
Now I am trying to write an app which needs both routing and pubnub.angular.service.

But when I injected both dependencies, I am getting following error
"Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string"
.....
return new ErrorConstructor(message);

The return statement is in anjular.js file.

Here is my index.html

```html
<head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.21.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/pubnub-angular/pubnub-angular-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

and here is the script.js entry

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"], ["pubnub.angular.service"]);
```

After adding the "pubnub.angular.service" dependency the error appears.
If I remove this dependency my code works fine (obviously no pubnub feature is there at that time.)

Can any one help on the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute','pubnub.angular.service']);
```

try this